# Multiple HTML Select - not expanding

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have multiple select elements in my page. But first one(math) is not expanding(it may expand first time when you click, but if you click again, it will stop working!).

I have tried Google Chrome and Safari browser. Also, validated the HTML. Not sure what is wrong!

Please check my code at
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZBCNDGK5B9A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're giving too much padding and your controls are falling outside of their box.

Try opening it in Chrome and right clicking on one of the selects and choose "Inspect" so you can see it on the developer tools, that'll probably give you a better feeling of what the problem is.

You're giving too little space for your controls. Try changing some of those `col-1` to `col-4`, that might help.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result,  give proper col-spacing for all divs inside each row

1. First adjust header divs spacing of col-6, class="col-6"
2. And class="col-6" inside each Student row to divided equally

**Issue:** overlapping of divs causing the issue of Math selection from dropdown

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <meta name="google" content="notranslate">
      <title>Title</title>
      <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <!-- Custom CSS -->
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12"><br></div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
               <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                  <div class="container">
                     <br/><br/><br/>
                     <div class="container">
                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-2"></div>
                           <div class="col-6">
                              <div class="row">
                                 <div class="col-1">Math</div>
                                 <div class="col-2"></div>
                                 <div class="col-1">Science</div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row ">
                           <div class="col-2">
                              Student1
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-3">
                              <div class="row">
                                 <div class="col-6">
                                    <div>
                                       <select name="name_student1_math" id="id_student1_math">
                                          <option value="na">N/A</option>
                                          <option value="1" >1</option>
                                          <option value="2" selected >2</option>
                                          <option value="3" >3</option>
                                          <option value="4" >4</option>
                                       </select>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-1"></div>
                                 <div class="col-3">
                                    <div>
                                       <select name="name_student1_science" id="id_student1_science">
                                          <option value="na">N/A</option>
                                          <option value="1" >1</option>
                                          <option value="2" >2</option>
                                          <option value="3" >3</option>
                                          <option value="4" selected >4</option>
                                          <option value="5" >5</option>
                                          <option value="6" >6</option>
                                          <option value="7" >7</option>
                                          <option value="8" >8</option>
                                          <option value="9" >9</option>
                                       </select>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row ">
                           <div class="col-2">
                              Student2
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-3">
                              <div class="row">
                                 <div class="col-6">
                                    <div>
                                       <select name="name_student2_math" id="id_student2_math">
                                          <option value="na">N/A</option>
                                          <option value="1" >1</option>
                                          <option value="2" selected >2</option>
                                          <option value="3" >3</option>
                                          <option value="4" >4</option>
                                       </select>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-1"></div>
                                 <div class="col-3">
                                    <div>
                                       <select name="name_student2_science" id="id_student2_science">
                                          <option value="na">N/A</option>
                                          <option value="1" >1</option>
                                          <option value="2" >2</option>
                                          <option value="3" >3</option>
                                          <option value="4" selected >4</option>
                                          <option value="5" >5</option>
                                          <option value="6" >6</option>
                                          <option value="7" >7</option>
                                          <option value="8" >8</option>
                                          <option value="9" >9</option>
                                       </select>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```